# Can two different struts Web application share same session and can I utilize the same for single sign on

Tags: session, struts2

I have two different struts2 Applications, tried implementing SessionAware but still other application is not able to use the session variables set by first application.
If I am doing something wrong or is it not possible the way I am doing. Thanks

Comment: This isn't anything Struts 2-related. You *may* be able to configure your server for some sort of session sharing. Of course by default apps don't share sessions--sessions are for a single app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**application, request, session and page** scoped objects are only specific to one application.

Session variable is not the solution for your problem.

Let your Single Sign-On Application send those variables to both the applications as custom attributes. Just like the authenticated user name.

Or use a Database table to share the session info.

Note: You will run into race conditions unless app2 access is initiated from app1.